# Django models - Does django cache former queries?

Tags: django, caching, django-models

Below I call the same methods in `author` and `w5` model objects. But one of them raises an error:

```
>>> author = models.Author('ali')
>>> author.article_set.count()
---------------------------------------------
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ali'

>>> w5 = models.Author(name='w5')
>>> w5.article_set.count()
0
```

Actually, before these lines I had previously a wrong `Author` class definition. I obtained the `ValueError` from author object first with that former definition of `Author`. Then I changed `Author` class and reloaded the modules.

After reloading the models with the [reloadmodels.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890924/how-do-you-reload-a-django-model-module-using-the-interactive-interpreter-via-ma/903943#903943) written by Chad Braun-Duin, newly instantiated objects like `w5` work properly. But reinstantiated objects like `author` raise errors.

Is this contradictory behavior due to django's query caching logic or reloadmodels.py? Have any idea?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't anything to do with Django, it's a Python thing. In the linked question, Chad was importing models like this:

```
import myapp.models as mymodels
```

Using this syntax, you can use `reload()` to refresh class definitions when you change them on disk. However, it's far more standard to import your models like this:

```
from myapp.models import MyModel
```

If you do this - and most people do - reload() has no effect, even with Chad's hack.

Really, it's more simple to just quit the Python shell and restart it - especially if you use `shell_plus` from [django-extensions](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/) which automatically loads your models into the shell on startup.

Comment: Thanks for the info. You are right, my code imports the models with "from ... import ..." command.
I will check shell_plus. But the problem with restart is that it takes a little time to start ipython shell. But anyway reloading statements take time too.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the model definitions in django, you need to re-apply your changes to the database. If you can manually drop the tables, you can restore the structure with `manage.py syncdb`

You can use the manage.py sql command to examine the SQL definitions that django would use to match your new model class, and manually edit the tables to fit, if you'd rather not lose the table.

Comment: I didn't change model definitions. I had only changed business logic.

Comment: I misunderstood, from where you said you changed the Author class definition, I thought that referred to a model change.