# How to reload Django models without losing my locals in an interactive session?

Tags: python, django, module, ipython

I'm doing some research with an interactive shell and using a Django app (shell_plus) for storing data and browsing it using the convenient admin.

Occasionally I add or change some of the app models, and run a syncdb (or South migration when changing a model). The changes to the models don't take effect in my interactive session even if I re-import the app models. Thus I'm forced to restart the shell_plus and lose my precious locals() in the process.

Is there any way to reload the models during a session?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890924/how-do-you-reload-a-django-model-module-using-the-interactive-interpreter-via-ma/903943#903943) to rebuild the AppCache. Do not forget to remove all *.pyc files if any by using something like:

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm {} \;
```

Otherwise the *reload()* will ignore your changes in your models.py file.

Comment: I deleted the *.pyc files and ran the snippet -- I see the models.pyc get created as soon as I run the snippet (none of the other pyc files get created at this point) but the model *still* doesn't get updated. (AttributeError when trying to access a newly added field) Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: I tried it using an ipython shell. Did you re-import your model classes after running the snippet?

Comment: Yes I did, still can't access the new attribute.

Comment: I did it like this: Add new field to model -> run syncdb -> clear pyc files -> run snippet -> re-import updated model -> create a new instance of the model -> access to newly added field
Maybe you can install ipython an try again. And you have to create new instances of the updated model I think.