# How to reload modules in django shell?

Tags: python, django, ipython

I am working with Django and use Django shell all the time. The annoying part is that while the Django server reloads on code changes, the shell does not, so every time I make a change to a method I am testing, I need to quit the shell and restart it, re-import all the modules I need, reinitialize all the variables I need etc. While iPython history saves a lot of typing on this, this is still a pain. Is there a way to make django shell auto-reload, the same way django development server does?

I know about reload(), but I import a lot of models and generally use `from app.models import *` syntax, so reload() is not much help.

Comment: You should update this question to mark the "django-extensions" answer correct.

Comment: Not until it actually works for me. I have the extensions installed and none of my code auto-reloads and I don't see any mention of auto-reloading in the shell_plus docs. It seems that there is a reloader in the runserver_plus command, but that is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I recommend using the django-extensions project like stated above by dongweiming. But instead of just 'shell_plus' management command, use:

```
manage.py shell_plus --notebook
```

This will open a IPython notebook on your web browser. Write your code there in a cell, your imports etc. and run it.

When you change your modules, just click the notebook menu item 'Kernel->Restart'

There you go, your code is now using your modified modules.

Comment: "Just use a python notebook" is not an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: This method, while not automatic like %autoreload, does work more reliably than autoreload. kernel restart guarantees that all the cells in the notebook get fully reloaded modules. Plus you can restart and run all cells if you choose.

Comment: I just get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook.notebookapp'`

Answer (score 128):

I'd suggest use IPython [autoreload extension](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html).

```
./manage.py shell

In [1]: %load_ext autoreload
In [2]: %autoreload 2
```

And from now all imported modules would be refreshed before evaluate.

```
In [3]: from x import print_something
In [4]: print_something()
Out[4]: 'Something'

 # Do changes in print_something method in x.py file.

In [5]: print_something()
Out[5]: 'Something else'
```

Works also if something was imported before `%load_ext autoreload` command.

```
./manage.py shell
In [1]: from x import print_something
In [2]: print_something()
Out[2]: 'Something'

 # Do changes in print_something method in x.py file.

In [3]: %load_ext autoreload
In [4]: %autoreload 2
In [5]: print_something()
Out[5]: 'Something else'
```

There is possible also prevent some imports from refreshing with `%aimport` command and 3 autoreload strategies:

> **%autoreload**
>
> - Reload all modules (except those excluded by %aimport) automatically
>     now.
>
> **%autoreload 0**
>
> - Disable automatic reloading.
>
> **%autoreload 1**
>
> - Reload all modules imported with %aimport every time before executing
>     the Python code typed.
>
> **%autoreload 2**
>
> - Reload all modules (except those excluded by %aimport) every time
>     before executing the Python code typed.
>
> **%aimport**
>
> - List modules which are to be automatically imported or not to be
>     imported.
>
> **%aimport foo**
>
> - Import module ‘foo’ and mark it to be autoreloaded for %autoreload 1
>
> **%aimport -foo**
>
> - Mark module ‘foo’ to not be autoreloaded.

This generally works good for my use, but there are some cavetas:

> - Replacing code objects does not always succeed: changing a @property in a class to an ordinary method or a method to a member variable can cause problems (but in old objects only).
> - Functions that are removed (eg. via monkey-patching) from a module before it is reloaded are not upgraded.
> - C extension modules cannot be reloaded, and so cannot be autoreloaded.

Comment: In case you are using django's `/manage.py shell_plus`... if you type `%load_ext autoreload` and then `%autoreload 2`, models will be automatically reloaded.

Comment: Note that you need ipython to be installed for this, obviously. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47170195/50899

Comment: where to put this %autoreload? It's not clear from the answer

Comment: Is there a way to automate this with `/manage.py shell_plus`, if I want to make it the default behaviour?

Answer (score 56):

My solution to it is I write the code and save to a file and then use:

> python manage.py shell < test.py

So I can make the change, save and run that command again till I fix whatever I'm trying to fix.

Comment: Nice and simple. One note, add ```exit()``` to the bottom of the py file to exit the Django shell in a cleaner fashion. Thx.

Comment: Simple and elegant solution. Good job.

Answer (score 32):

look at the manage.py shell_plus command provided by the [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) project. It will load all your model files on shell startup. and autoreload your any modify but do not need exit, you can direct call there

Comment: I use shell_plus and my models are not auto-reloading, am I missing something?

Comment: shell_plus doesn't reload models, so this does not answer the question.

Comment: as said, shell_plus doesn't reload models.

Comment: I'm using shell_plus right now and my models are reloading as soon as I change the code. I even just changed the definition of a model, and an instance in my shell picked up the change.  This should be accepted as the correct answer.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but shell_plus doesn't reload anything for me. It loads all models at startup, which is convenient, but that is that.

Comment: shell_plus CAN reload modules using the autoreload module. Type '%load_ext autoreload' and then '%autoreload 2' - see https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html

Answer (score 27):

It seems that the general consensus on this topic, is that python reload() sucks and there is no good way to do this.

Comment: Incorrect.  @dongweiming's answer above is the solution, and should be accepted as the best answer.

Comment: Multiple comments on his answer say that shell_plus doesn't reload models

Comment: I have just tested it myself and it doesn't reload. Besides, what about non-model code I import by hand?

Comment: Classes in an app I'm using now reload great (Python 3.4.3, Django 1.9b1, django-extensions 1.5.9), including a plain non-django-model module and the class within it. It's 5 years since this answer, and a lot of development has happened.

Comment: I have tried it on my setup 40 minutes ago and shell_plus doesn't reload anything for me. Django 1.7.10, python 3.4.3, django-extensions 1.5.9.

Comment: Good data points. Let's try to figure out the secret combination of things that will help it work for you. Can you try updating Django?

Comment: No, my project needs 1.7 at the moment. I have checked the docs and nothing anywhere says that shell_plus reloads things. The runserver_plus command does reloads, but not the shell.

Comment: Do you have ipython installed? It probably won't work if you're just using the  plain python shell.

Comment: Yes, I have ipython. Version is 4.0.0

Comment: Upgraded to Django 1.8. Same thing, no reloads.

Comment: I've been using Django since 1.6 and now I'm using 1.10 (tested all versions between) in none of these versions (always latest django-extensions at the time) it auto reloads. (python 2.6 to 3.5)

Answer (score 17):

Use [shell_plus](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/docs/shell_plus.rst#shell_plus) with an ipython config.  This will enable `autoreload` before shell_plus automatically imports anything.

```
pip install django-extensions
pip install ipython
ipython profile create
```

Edit your ipython profile (`~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`):

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%autoreload 2']
c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = ['autoreload']
```

Open a shell - note that you do not need to include `--ipython`:

```
python manage.py shell_plus
```

Now anything defined in `SHELL_PLUS_PRE_IMPORTS` or `SHELL_PLUS_POST_IMPORTS` ([docs](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/docs/shell_plus.rst#additional-imports)) will autoreload!

Note that if your shell is at a debugger (ex `pdb.set_trace()`) when you save a file it can interfere with the reload.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You might note though, that I asked it in 2010. I am glad to know that after eight years auto-reload finally works in shell_plus :)

Comment: I tried this, it didnt work, i also added to `SHELL_PLUS_PRE_IMPORTS` and `SHELL_PLUS_POST_IMPORTS`

Comment: This is very neat

Comment: Still gives warnings: `RuntimeWarning: Model 'xxx.xxxxxx' was already registered. Reloading models is not advised as it can lead to inconsistencies, most notably with related models`. Beware.

Answer (score 8):

My solution for this inconvenient follows. I am using IPython.

```
$ ./manage.py shell
> import myapp.models as mdls   # 'mdls' or whatever you want, but short...
> mdls.SomeModel.objects.get(pk=100)
> # At this point save some changes in the model
> reload(mdls)
> mdls.SomeModel.objects.get(pk=100)
```

For **Python 3.x**, 'reload' must be imported using:

```
from importlib import reload
```

Hope it helps. Of course it is for debug purposes.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Reload() doesn't work in Django shell without some tricks. You can check this thread na and my answer specifically:

[How do you reload a Django model module using the interactive interpreter via "manage.py shell"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890924/how-do-you-reload-a-django-model-module-using-the-interactive-interpreter-via-ma/3466579#3466579)

Answer (score 3):

Using a combination of 2 answers for this I came up with a simple one line approach.

You can run the django shell with -c which will run the commands you pass however it **quits** immediately after the code is run.

The trick is to setup what you need, run code.interact(local=locals()) and then re-start the shell from within the code you pass. Like this:

```
python manage.py shell -c 'import uuid;test="mytestvar";import code;code.interact(local=locals())'
```

For me I just wanted the rich library's inspect method. Only a few lines:

```
python manage.py shell -c 'import code;from rich import pretty;pretty.install();from rich import inspect;code.interact(local=locals())'
```

Finally the cherry on top is an alias

```
alias djshell='python manage.py shell -c "import code;from rich import pretty;pretty.install();from rich import inspect;code.interact(local=locals())"'
```

Now if I startup my shell and say, want to inspect the form class I get this beautiful output:
[image]

Comment: I love the idea of injecting Rich. However the `code.interact(local=locals())` part does not seem to work with ipython. When I run the same command than you with `shell_plus` rather than `shell`, I still get a normal shell instead of a ipython shell.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you want, but I now tend to build myself management commands for testing and fiddling with things.

In the command you can set up a bunch of locals the way you want and afterwards drop into an interactive shell.

```
import code

class Command(BaseCommand):
  def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
     foo = 'bar'
     code.interact(local=locals())
```

No reload, but an easy and less annoying way to interactively test django functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running commands from the Django shell, you can set up a management command [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853649/executing-python-script-from-django-shell/16853755#16853755) and rerun that each time.

Answer (score 0):

```
import test  // test only has x defined
test.x       // prints 3, now add y = 4 in test.py
test.y       // error, test does not have attribute y
```

**solution Use reload from importlib as follows**

```
from importlib import reload
import test // test only has x defined
test.x // prints 3, now add y = 4 in test.py
test.y // error
reload(test)
test.y // prints 4
```