# IPython/Django shell do not recognize changes/edits on imported files

Tags: python, django, ipython

I'm using IPython shell to play with my Python/DJango code before running it on the server.

In order to be able to run my code on the shell, I'm using the import directive:

```
from tag_analytics.functions import WriteTagGroupMatrix
```

After detecting some errors or improvements to be done, I edit the file where `WriteTagGroupMatrix` is written, try to import again, but it seems like IPython do not accept or recognize the changes.

Is there any way to solve this (obviously without restarting IPython)?

Thanks a lot,
alan

Comment: Some possibilities were discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772260/how-to-reload-modules-in-django-shell?rq=1, without actually reaching a consensus.

Comment: You may want the IPython [autoreload extension](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html?highlight=autoreload).