# Run Django shell in IPython

Tags: django

I attempt to run a Django shell in IPython:

```
ipython manage.py shell
```

It reports the following error:

> Type 'manage.py help ' for help on a specific subcommand.

I searched and found a popular solution which guides you to install `django.extensions` and to enable it in `settings`.

I am creating a minimal project while the solution is heavy.
Meanwhile, I have to install and enable it on every project.

Is there a lightweight way?

I start a new project, 
`python manage.py shell -i ipython` fails to work

```
$ python manage.py shell -i ipython
CommandError: Couldn't import ipython interface.
$ ipython --version
6.4.0
```

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Simply install `ipython` into your virtualenv. [`manage.py shell`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/django-admin/#shell) should use it by default.

You can also use `manage.py shell` with the [`-i` option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-shell-interface) to explicitly select a shell (the options are `ipython`, `bpython`, or `python` for a regular Python shell):

```
python manage.py shell -i ipython
```

Either way, you do need to install `ipython` into your environment, but you don't need to make any changes to your project settings.

Comment: I prefer this way. It lead me right to browser instead of ipython shell. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54856080/5739514

Answer (score 14):

I appreciate above answer and based on that I have written this answer.

If **`ipython`** is already installed in your **`virtualenv`** then any of the below command will work same (which has been already presented below after commands with sample snippets, point wise).

- `python manage.py shell`
- `python manage.py -i ipython`

---

#### `How I solved (steps with problem & solution)?`

> **Note:** Make sure you have already activated your **`virtualenv`**.

1. I didn't have **`ipython`** installed in my Django project. Below is the error I got while trying to run Django shell in **`ipython`** environment.

```py
(venv3.6.7) Rishikeshs-MacBook-Air:src hygull$ python manage.py shell -i ipython
CommandError: Couldn't import ipython interface.
(venv3.6.7) Rishikeshs-MacBook-Air:src hygull$
```

Next I installed **`ipython`** using below command.

2. `pip install ipython`

```py
(venv3.6.7) Rishikeshs-MacBook-Air:src hygull$ pip install ipython
Collecting ipython
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/d7/77b7a1988c99227f52402f93fb0f7e88c97239960516f53907ebbc44149c/ipython-7.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (777kB)
   ...
   ...
     |████████████████████████████████| 102kB 524kB/s 
Installing collected packages: ipython-genutils, six, decorator, traitlets, pygments, ptyprocess, pexpect, wcwidth, prompt-toolkit, backcall, parso, jedi, appnope, pickleshare, ipython
Successfully installed appnope-0.1.0 backcall-0.1.0 decorator-4.4.1 ipython-7.11.0 ipython-genutils-0.2.0 jedi-0.15.2 parso-0.5.2 pexpect-4.7.0 pickleshare-0.7.5 prompt-toolkit-3.0.2 ptyprocess-0.6.0 pygments-2.5.2 six-1.13.0 traitlets-4.3.3 wcwidth-0.1.7
(venv3.6.7) Rishikeshs-MacBook-Air:src hygull$
```

3.a) `python manage.py shell -i ipython`

```py
(venv3.6.7) Rishikeshs-MacBook-Air:src hygull$ python manage.py shell -i ipython
Python 3.6.7 (v3.6.7:6ec5cf24b7, Oct 20 2018, 03:02:14) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.11.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: exit()
```

3.b) `python manage.py shell`

```py
(venv3.6.7) Rishikeshs-MacBook-Air:src hygull$ python manage.py shell
Python 3.6.7 (v3.6.7:6ec5cf24b7, Oct 20 2018, 03:02:14) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.11.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]:
```

Thank you.