# How can I execute Python Django runserver command in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, django, jupyter-notebook

I am new for Python，Django & Jupyter Notebook.
And I tried my best to search and study from StackOverflow and get the Python Django and Jupyter Notebook work together. But when I tried to execute the python manage.py runserver command in the cell and get error message such as syntax error. So can anyone help me to solve this problem.
My environment is Windows 10 Pro x64 with Python 3.5 Django 2.10 Jupyter Notebook 4.0

Comment: because it is a shell command, not python code. just start the django dev server from a different terminal.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that your are trying to launch 'python' inside python/jupyter notebook.

```
python manage.py runserver
```

A general answer is to see it as a simple shell commands (not sure it can work with this particular command):

```
!python manage.py runserver
```

**Debug Django in jupyter**

1. Install  [django-extension](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shell_plus.html)
2. Add it to your django app in setting.py `INSTALLED_APPS = (..., 'django_extensions',...)`
3. Run `python manage.py shell_plus --notebook`

You will be able to access your model from jupyter.

Comment: O.K, maybe I mis-understand what Jupyter Notebook can do for me. Why I want to execute the runserver command ? because I suppose that I can debug the Django Project in the Jupyter Notebook environment. Can I ?

Comment: Yes. You can do that. I have edited my answer to explain better.

Answer (score 0):

you can find a description for an
[installation with win10, Python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35483328/how-to-setup-jupyter-ipython-notebook-for-django). With python 3.6 you just start a new "python" notebook ("django-shell" is no longer there).

With win10 you need an open CMD. After you have started the CMD, change to the directory where your Jupyter/Django notebook is running. In this CMD you run:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

To be honest: with that I can run my example given there:

```
from django.template import Template, Context

template = Template('The name of this project is {{ projectName }}')
context = Context({'projectName': 'MyJypyterDjangoSite'})
template.render(context)
```

but I still have troubles myself when I want to work with templates-files to be included. Perhaps I should try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47170049/run-django-shell-in-ipython?rq=1) or [this](https://maneeshasane.com/programming/2016/11/jupyter-notebook-and-the-django-shell.html)