# Python: Define a module by several files

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose I have a python module called `mymodule`. At the top of my Code, I have this:

```
import mymodule
reload(mymodule)
```

where my directory structure is

```
/dir/mymodule.py
```

However, I would like to split `mymodule.py` into several files, while still being defined as a single module (i.e. I don't want to have to import each file separately - I want to be able to use my import/reload as before).

The only way I know how to do this is the following

```
/dir/mymodule/
             file1.py
             file2.py
             __init__.py
```

where `__init__.py` contains

```
from file1 import *
from file2 import *
```

This mostly works, but my call to `reload(mymodule)` no longer does anything, because it doesn't reload anything called via * imports.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this too.  What is the reason for this desired pattern?

Comment: Why do you need to import module and then reload it at once?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is your code structured like this?

Comment: I have a lot of common functions that I import under the same module, and the single file module started getting long, so I decided to break it into several files.  My module is already nested, in another module, and I didn't want to keep nesting.

Comment: Your missing the `__all__` statement in your __init__.py.  `__all__` = ['file1','file2'] testing now before I put this as an answer

Comment: Ixanezis - I import the module at the beginning of my code and then reload it immediately in case I've made changes to functions in my module.  I do this all inside of iPython, and without reloading it I have to close iPython and open it again.

Comment: @David I tried that, but my understanding was that the `__all__` statement only helps if you're doing a * import

Comment: What version of Python are you using? with/without `__all__` reload didn't lose any properties after reload in Pyth 2.7.4

Comment: @rottweiler Also, not relevant to question but I'd highly recommend not using import * inside an `__init__.py` file as it makes it very tedious for someone else to understand where things came from and what they're doing.  Ideally code is write once, read many times.

Comment: I'm using 2.7.2.  I tried using `__all__ = ['file1', 'file2']` and now to import things from `file1.py` I need to call
`import mymodule.file1`, instead of just `import mymodule`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly why you're doing this, but will assume you have you reasons. I think this works:

`__init__.py:`

```
import file1
reload(file1)
from file1 import *
```

Obviously you can import file2 as well

Comment: Please edit your post to add backticks around `__init__.py`... right now it is showing in bold.  I can't edit it because it wants me to change 6 characters, but the backticks is only two characters.

Comment: David nicely did it for me.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't endorse it?  Seems like a pretty good workaround.

Comment: I just mean that the whole situation seems a little strange (reloading your module and using star imports etc), so I'm suggesting this as exactly what you say it is: a workaround. I've edited my answer though.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick workaround I could suggest

```
import sys

def myreload(base_module_name):
    for module_name, module in sys.modules.items():
        if module_name.startswith(base_module_name):
            reload(module)

myreload('mymodule')
```

This would call `reload(mymodule.file1)`, `reload(mymodule.file2)` etc.

However, it is not recursive and as you are using ipython, I believe your quiestion is well answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364050/reloading-submodules-in-ipython).