# Reusing code from different IPython notebooks

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am using IPython and want to run functions from one notebook from another (without cutting and pasting them between different notebooks). Is this possible and reasonably easy to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect with a qtconsole to the same kernel. Just supply this at startup:

```
ipython qtconsole --existing kernel-0300435c-3d07-4bb6-abda-8952e663ddb7.json
```

Look at the output after starting the notebook for the long string.

Comment: How can I grab the "long string" inside the console? How can I paste it ?

Comment: What OS? Window, Linux or Mac?

Comment: Windows 7. I cannot select or move the cursor inside the window

Comment: Use the mouse. Highlight, right mouse button, copy.

Comment: This could not work. I used right clic -> mark, then selected the zone, and then pressed enter. Cheers though

Comment: Yes, if you have quick edit mode on it works like this.

Answer (score 38):

Starting your notebook server with:

```
ipython notebook --script
```

will save the notebooks (`.ipynb`) as Python scripts (`.py`) as well, and you will be able to import them.

Or have a look at: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/5491090/ that contains 2 notebook, one executing the other.

Comment: If you like notebook names that aren't valid python module names (eg: containing things like spaces and dots), you won't be able to `import` them. You can use the `%run` magic however.

Comment: You *can* actually import from any filename, it just takes a few more keystrokes. See the `imp` module.

Comment: The notebook you link to provides the best answer to the question: `analysis.ipynb` defines a function `execute_notebook` that will run all code in another notebook. (Not sure what namespace this happens in.)

Comment: The referenced IPython notebook does not exist anymore.

Comment: I fail to reimport the .py script. I get a the entire code block into one cell with %loadpy test.py where test.py is a script created with ipython notebook --script. import "test.py" is illegal syntax and import test.py runs forever without a result

Comment: @tschm if you want to use python's `import` command, the syntax would be `import test` (without the .py). Note that in the current head version of ipython, the --script option is disabled...

Comment: The `--script` parameter was removed in 3.0: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/whatsnew/version3.html#backwards-incompatible-changes. The replacement is `ipython nbconvert --to python notebook` (or one of the other methods mentioned in this question.

Comment: I change functions notebook, reload import but function used in other notebook is still the same. How to manage this?

Answer (score 28):

In IPython 2.0 you can simply `%run 'my_shared_code.ipynb'` to share code between notebooks. See for example http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/edrex/9044756.

Answer (score 15):

Ipythons `%run` magic allows you execute python files and ipython scripts in a notebook. I sometimes use the `-i` option so it runs in the notebooks namespace. Execute a cell with `%run?` in it for more info.

You can use the `ipython --script` to save notebooks also as `.py` files on each save or uncomment the line `c.NotebookManager.save_script=True` in your `ipython_notebook_config.py` file for the same effect (use `ipython profile create` for setting that up - on Ubuntu the config files live in `~/.config/ipython/`).

**Edit:** The following is true, but unnecessary - you can `%run` a `.ipynb` file directly. Thanks [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114581/eric-drechsel).

<s>If you use ipython magics in the notebook you want to import, I found that you can rename the `.py` file to `.ipy` (an ipython script), but I had to remove the first line (which contained the file encoding declaration) for it to work. There is probably a better way! This approach will likely confuse cell magics too (they'd all get applied at once).</s>

Comment: you can `%run 'my_notebook.ipynb'`, which would make your answer a lot simpler.

Comment: Note that --script is no longer valid with Jupyter.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a "write and execute" extension, which will let you write the content of a cell to a file (and replace old content -> update code), which can then be imported in another notebook.

https://github.com/minrk/ipython_extensions#write-and-execute

In one notebook (two cells)

```
%reload_ext writeandexecute
--
%%writeandexecute -i some_unique_string functions.py
def do_something(txt):
    print(txt)
```

And then in the other notebook:

```
from functions import do_something
do_something("hello world")
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can *"run functions from one notebook from another (without cutting and pasting them between different notebooks)"* -- and, yes, it's easy to do!

**tl;dr:** put the code in python files (`*.py`) in the file system & let multiple notebooks use the same code. (It's that simple.)

*(Why put so much code in notebooks, when we have perfectly good code editors & IDEs that are so much better for writing & reading code? Not to mention the need for proper version control! What are we trying to achieve, and at what expense? `</rant>`)*

**Details:**

- Put your code in normal python files, eg `my_code/foo.py`, adding a (probably empty) `my_code/__init__.py`
- Take advantage of having the code under proper version control (eg git) -- notice how hard it was to diff ipynb json files?
- Also put the notebooks also under version control. Raw git logs will be hard to read, but the comments can be useful. (GitHub/GitLab displays ipython notebooks, btw.)
- Limit the py source in the ipynb notebook to small amounts of "driver" code, and output, and documentation.
- See also: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html
- If you want to "inline" the external python files, just use (for example) magic `%cat my_code/foo.py` ...

...If you want something fancier to display that source inline (optionally, adding the following to an external, reusable source file)...

```
import IPython
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter
from pygments.lexers import get_lexer_for_filename

filename='my_code/foo.py'
with open(filename) as f: code = f.read()
formatter = HtmlFormatter(linenos='inline')
IPython.display.HTML('<style type="text/css">{}</style>{}'.format(
                formatter.get_style_defs('.highlight'),
                highlight(code, get_lexer_for_filename(filename), formatter)))
```

Your favorite code editors & IDEs thank you for your support.

Comment: this is not very practical because you need to restart the ipython kernel to reload changes in a `.py` file that you are importing.

Comment: @sarfata not true, see https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html Editing code in a browser will always, imho, be inferior — all caveats considered — to using a proper IDE with an actual debugger & related dev tools. As useful as they are, Notebooks are a poor substitute, and were never intended to be.

Comment: you might want to edit your answer to mention `%autoreload` then. thank you.

Comment: Totally agree what you said and also is what I am doing. Auto reload works. And you can debug the cell and enter into your python source code. Version control is way better in py files than notebooks.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two additional tips:

1. You can also run `%qtconsole` magic directly from the notebook and it will automatically connect to the notebook kernel.
2. Check out https://github.com/atiasnir/ipnb

   You can use it to import notebook files as if they're standard python modules (I'm the author :-)). Main limitation here is that it will discard magic cells (because it does not use IPython at all) but otherwise it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I do call notebooks from other notebooks. You can even pass "parameters" to other notebooks using the following trick:

Place ***params*** dictionary **in the first cell** of "report_template.ipynb".

```
params = dict(platform='iOS', 
              start_date='2016-05-01', 
              retention=7)
df = get_data(params ..)
do_analysis(params ..)
```

And in another (higher logical level) notebook, execute it using this function:

```
def run_notebook(nbfile, **kwargs):
    """
    example:
    run_notebook('report.ipynb', platform='google_play', start_date='2016-06-10')
    """

    def read_notebook(nbfile):
        if not nbfile.endswith('.ipynb'):
            nbfile += '.ipynb'

        with io.open(nbfile) as f:
            nb = nbformat.read(f, as_version=4)
        return nb

    ip = get_ipython()
    gl = ip.ns_table['user_global']
    gl['params'] = None
    arguments_in_original_state = True

    for cell in read_notebook(nbfile).cells:
        if cell.cell_type != 'code':
            continue
        ip.run_cell(cell.source)

        if arguments_in_original_state and type(gl['params']) == dict:
            gl['params'].update(kwargs)
            arguments_in_original_state = False

run_notebook("report_template.ipynb", start_date='2016-09-01')
```

This command will execute each cell of the "report_template" notebook and will override relevant keys of ***params*** dictionary **starting from the second cell**

Answer (score 1):

I use the following function in the notebook from which I want to load functions or actions from a source notebook:

```
import io
import nbformat

def execute_notebook(nbfile):
    with io.open(nbfile, encoding="utf8") as f:
        nb = nbformat.read(f, as_version=4)

    ip = get_ipython()

    for cell in nb.cells:
        if cell.cell_type != 'code':
            continue
        ip.run_cell(cell.source)
```

Use like:

```
execute_notebook(path/to/notebook.ipynb)
```

Answer (score 0):

So @MikeMuller's good idea will work for a local notebook, but not a remote one (right?). I don't think there is a way for you to remotely invoke individual cell blocks or functions of ipynb code on a remote server and be able to get results back into your calling routine programmatically, unless that code does something fairly extraordinary to communicate results.

I was in the process of writing when @Matt submitted the same idea about

`ipython <URI_to_Notebook> --script`

The *.pynb is a JSON container and not an actual python script. You can get ipython to export a *.py with

If the target *.ipynb is on a remote machine you don't control, you'll probably need to pull the file so that you can write the output to a local path. (Haven't looked into whether you can invoke this on a remote resource to create a local output.) Once this is created you should be able to import and run the *.py or individual functions within it.

A question for @Matt on that neat example of running another *.ipynb file wholesale with `io.open(nbfile)` is whether the nbfile can be remote? Seems like a long shot, but would be great...

Comment: yes, the notebook can be remote, but you will just have to fetch it with a tool like requests. It can also be stored as json in mongo db.. or whatever. Once loaded it just a pure python dict/list nested. There should even be a way to define some cells that would not be executed on import with a tool like that.