# import object from one datalab notebook into another

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

Is it possible to reference a datalab object created in one notebook from a different notebook running on the same datalab instance?

Specifically, I would like to reference a big query query constructed using the following syntax:

```
%%bq query --name myQry
SELECT * FROM etc
```

In a different notebook to which it was created but I suspect the same answer will apply whether the object in question is a BigQuery query object or not.

I couldn't find anything in the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18221612/2455494) on a similar IPython question.

If you use the `%run` magic like this:

```
%run 'theReferencedNotebook.ipynb'
```

then you can reference all the objects declared in 'theReferenceNotebook.ipynb' (including any bigquery queries) in the new notebook.

For example this cell would get a sample from the `myQry` query defined on the other notebook:

```
%%bq sample -q myQry
```