# Call a function written in different file from jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

From a jupyter notebook, I'd like to call a function written in another `.ipynb` file. The partial answer is given in this thread [Reusing code from different IPython notebooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966280/reusing-code-from-different-ipython-notebooks) by [drevicko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420867/drevicko). As an example, I'm using `plus_one` function written in `plus_one.ipynb`:

```
def plus_one(x):
    print(x + 1)
```

Then, in my current notebook, I execute the cell:

```
%run plus_one.ipynb 3
```

which gives me no output. My expected output is `4`. How to pass an argument (`3`) to this script? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the `%run?` documentation

> This is similar to running at a system prompt `python file args`,
>   but with the advantage of giving you IPython's tracebacks, and of
>   loading all variables into your interactive namespace for further use

so all the cells from `plus_one.ipynb` are run and all it's variables are added to the namespace of the calling notebook. 
This does not call the `plus_one` method directly (unless it is called in the other notebook), but it defines it in the current namespace, kind of like an `import` in a regular python script.so from that moment on, you should be able to do  `plus_one(3)` in the calling notebook, and expect 4 as return value

Comment: Bingo! It works as described. Thanks a lot! (sorry don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer...)

Comment: thanks for explaining it well.
Although i had to rerun %run notebook command two three times, before it actually registered the function in the current namespace.