# IPython not recognizing updated module

Tags: python, numpy, ipython

I have a function in a script problem1.py:

```
def normal_method(target):
    a = np.array(np.arange(1,target))
    divisible_numbers = a[(a%3==0)|(a%5==0)]
    sum_value = np.sum(divisible_numbers)
    print sum_value
```

While calling this function in an IPython window using ,

```
import numpy as np
from problem1 import normal_method
%timeit normal_method(100)
```

It gives me TypeError saying normal_method takes no arguments. But when I paste the function into IPython and then call it using the same statement it works.
Any ideas why this occurs?

Comment: As a side note: repesenting `natural_numbers` as `a` you are better off writing `divisible_numbers = a[(a%3==0) | (a%5==0)]` to avoid the for loop.

Comment: It could be the fact that `problem1.py` does not have `import numpy as np`, could be something strange with `IPython` error reporting. It would be an issue without `IPython`.

Comment: @Ophion The script has the import statement and runs fine when called from the IPython console. It is only when I import the function that it gives the error.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue on OSX, do you have other issues importing functions?

Comment: So I ran into another issue..if I declare a function as `def ihn(): print np.arange(5)` and I try to do `from problem1 import ihn`, it does not even acknowledge ihn. But if I do `import problem1`, then I can use ihn. Strange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the interactive Python is not reloading the module.

[Take a look here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5364050/832621)
You can try:

```
import problem1
problem1 = reload(problem1)
%timeit problem1.normal_method(10)
```

Or just run from a command prompt shell:

```
python test.py
```

With `test.py` containing:

```
import numpy as np
from problem1 import normal_method
%timeit normal_method(100)
```

This is more robust and should be the prefered method if you are doing multiple imports from different new modules.

Comment: The first method works. I think you meant `%timeit problem1.normal_method(10)`. Can we use %timeit in a script?

Comment: yes you are right... you can use timeit in a script, [check here for instance...](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8220801/832621)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have "import numpy as np" in the problem1.py file, so at the scope of the function definition, the ref to np is invalid, and that error may be making the definition unavailable in the caller.

Once you put the "import numpy as np" in the module file, things so=hould be all right.

Comment: I have `import numpy as np` in my script. I have only posted the function in the post. It seems that there is a delay/load problem in IPython. If you restart IPython and reload the module, it works.