# Auto-reload extension not reloading on change

Tags: python, ipython

Ipython Version used: 2.3.1

Auto-reload extension of ipython isn't working for me. I have already seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364050/reloading-submodules-in-ipython) and tried various combinations of it in my `ipython_config.py` including:

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = ['autoreload']
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%autoreload 2']
```

Also tried a new option:

```
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.deep_reload = True
```

But none seem to be working. I also tried loading the extension at the ipython shell:

```
In [7]: %load_ext autoreload
The autoreload extension is already loaded. To reload it, use:
  %reload_ext autoreload

In [8]: %autoreload 2
```

So, it seems the extension have already loaded. But when I edit and save my file, it's not getting reloaded (Returning the same old value of my test function). Any ideas on what may be wrong ?

Comment: I'm using ipython 2.3.0 and that works for me, so I'm not sure that it's a config file issue. Will post what I have below so you can double check. Maybe post the test py you're using?

Comment: @AidanKane This is the [ipython configuration](https://gist.github.com/psibi/ecd8ef354b393ced87cf) file. and this is the [test script](https://gist.github.com/psibi/6a82d667695419091766)

Comment: Definitely looks ok. I'd double check by stripping everything out and just leaving the lines you need, but really, it looks fine. Try running the very simple test I posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Config that's working perfectly for me in ipython 2.3.0

```
c = get_config()
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%autoreload 2']
c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = ['autoreload']
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.autoindent = False
```

Try testing with something very simple:

test.py

```
def print_something():
    print('thing')
```

ipython

```
>>> import test
>>> test.print_something()
thing
>>> # change 'thing' -> 'other'
>>> test.print_something()
other
```

Comment: Thanks, figured that out. Emacs seems to be masking it. :)

Comment: Damn you emacs! *quietly turns back to his vim session with a wry smile* :)

Comment: I get `get_config() is not defined`

Comment: You’re adding this in you profile’s configuration. See here for details https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html#setting-configurable-options