# IPython autoreload changes in subdirectory

Tags: python, ipython

I launch IPython from the main folder `/project`. Now if I make changes in the file `/project/tests/some_module.py`, the changes fail to be autoreloaded in IPython. Also, I get the following message after I save the changes and want to run some other script in the prompt:

```
[autoreload of some_module failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/extensions/autoreload.py", line 229, in check
    superreload(m, reload, self.old_objects)
ImportError: No module named some_module]
```

It seems it detects changes were made inside folder `/tests` but it cannot import it. Can someone help me with this?

**Edit:**
For better clarification: I launch IPython from the terminal in the main folder. In this folder, I have another folder `tests`. Inside `tests` I have two python files:

**some_module.py**:

```
def hello_world():
  print "Hello World!!!"
```

**use_some_module.py**:

```
from some_module import hello_world

hello_world()
```

Once I launched IPython, further changes in *some_module.py* won't be loaded in IPython. For example, if I add a second `print "Hello Earth!!!"` in the definition of `hello_world()`, and run `run tests/use_some_module.py`, I get the error message shown above, and will only get the `"Hello World!!!"` print.

**Edit2**: I would like a solution where I don't need to either change the working directory, or adding any search paths manually. I want it to be loaded automatically with autoreload.

Comment: How do yo import your module the first time? Do you change the working directory between first import and reload?

Comment: @michael from your Edit2, the error `ImportError: No module named some_module` means, the `superreload` function of `autoreload` module couldn't find `some_module` because `some_module` isn't in search path.

Comment: @NizamMohamed If I exit ipython and relaunch it again in the same parent directory, the changes get updated.

Comment: @NizamMohamed So, what I want is for it to do it automatically every time there is a change in `tests/`. I have `autoreload 2` added in my ipython config file already, and it does the job for changes in the same directory I launched ipython in, but it isn't able to do the job for changes in the subdirectory. I want a solution that I can add to my ipython config file so that it does it automatically.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is to reload a changed file in Python just do the following:

```
from main import some_module
....
reload(some_module)
```

But if your reload purposes are really eager, you can do the following (taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364050/reloading-submodules-in-ipython)):

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

The previous code will reload all changed modules every time before executing a new line.

*NOTE:* You can also check [dreload](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.10.1/html/interactive/reference.html#dreload) which does a recursive reload of a module, and [%run](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.10.1/html/interactive/tutorial.html#the-run-magic-command) which allows you to run any python script and load all of its data directly into the interactive namespace.

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 2):

Module `/project/tests/some_module.py` must be importable from `/project`. It means `/project/tests` must be in `sys.path`.

Either change to `/project/tests` and `%run use_some_module.py` or do `sys.path.insert(0,tests)` to insert `tests` into module search path.

If `some_module` is not in search path, IPython's `autoreload` never gonna find it.

Another way to make it work is to make the `tests` a package by creating `__init__.py` in it. And use relative import in `use_some_module` as `from .some_module import hello_world`. Now do these from IPython prompt,

```
In [1]: load_ext autoreload

In [2]: %autoreload 2

In [3]: from tests import some_module

In [4]: run -m tests.use_some_module
Hello World!!!
In [5]: ed tests/some_module.py
"tests/some_module.py" 3L, 69C written
 done. Executing edited code...
In [6]: run -m tests.use_some_module
Hello World!!!
Hello World!!!
```

That's you have to run `use_some_module` module in the `tests` package as a script.

The first time you do `%run tests/use_some_module.py`, which is run as if you were running `python tests/use_some_module.py`. So `/project/tests` which the script is in, is automatically included in `sys.path`. That's why `from some_module import hello_world` in `use_some_module` succeeds. Additionally, after the run, objects in `use_some_module`'s global namespace are available in IPython session.

But when you change `tests/some_module`, it has to be loaded again to see the changes. To `reload` it manually, it has to be imported first. Now `import` should succeed because `use_some_module` imported it first when it was run, `some_module` is in `sys.modules`. But `reload` to succeed, `some_moudle` has to be in search path. So, even manual `reload` would fail let alone `autoreload`.

```
In [2]: #before %run  
In [3]: 'some_module' in globals()
Out[3]: False

In [6]: 'some_module' in sys.modules
Out[6]: False

In [7]: 'hello_world' in globals()
Out[7]: False

In [8]: run tests/use_some_module.py
Hello World!!!

In [9]: 'some_module' in globals()
Out[9]: False

In [11]: 'some_module' in sys.modules
Out[11]: True

In [12]: 'hello_world' in globals()
Out[12]: True
In [13]: import some_module

In [14]: some_module = reload(some_module)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-47e3c0de23e1> in <module>()
----> 1 some_module = reload(some_module)

ImportError: No module named some_module
```

Another solution is to start IPython as `PYTHONPATH=tests ipython` to include `tests` directory in `sys.path`.
Or set this `c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['import sys','sys.path.insert(0,"tests")']` in `ipython_config.py`.
.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm kind of new in Python, so I am not sure if I understand it fully. Why is it that autoreload is not clever enough to look up in the same path as the file I'm running? (ie. `tests/`). I mean, it does it in the first `run`, but later it doesn't anymore. BTW: I didn't downvoted you.

Comment: look at [search path](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) for more info. I've already answered you question. The first run imports `hello_world` from `some_module`. Subsequent runs from the same session won't re-import an already imported module. That's why we need `reload`. But the `reload` can't see a module which in not in search path. You have to tell it to look up in some paths. `autoreload` is automatic version of `reload`. `autoreload` and `%run` are two different things. `%run` is IPython's mechanism to run an external module.

Comment: Can't `reload` automatically include `tests/` in the `sys.path` like `%run` does?

Comment: `%run` uses `execfile`. Check the syntax of `execfile` and `reload`. `execfile` uses path name `reload` uses an already loaded module name.

Comment: Followed everything and nothing worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: @DeanLa what didn't work? what was the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your file `use_some_module.py` to:

```
import some_module

some_module.hello_world()
```

Reload with `from import` usually does not work.

This works for me:

```
%autoreload 1
%aimport use_some_module
%aimport some_module
```

Comment: No luck. Are you able to replicate my problem?