# ipython autoreload doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook

autoreload doesn't work for me in subdirs at all.

dir structure:

```
run.ipynb
oof.py
pertussis/
    |-- __init__.py
```

on **run.ipynb** I have (running with notebook):

```
from pertussis import *
check() #defined in the module
```

this doesn't work. I tried everything. I added the autoreload magic inside code, inside config file, everywhere. I also added the folder of the module to the sys.path list. Never reloaded. I tried reloading a regular file `oof.py` from the notebook, instead of the module directly.

on **oof.py** I have:

```
from pertussis import *
def check_2():
  print ("Hello")
```

What happend now is that check_2 was autoreloaded successfully, but check from the module still didn't reload.

Nothing seems to work, I am lost.

Comment: Am running python 3.5 on Anaconda 4 on win 10

Comment: Also tries everything here with no luck:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33106590/ipython-autoreload-changes-in-subdirectory

Comment: Sharing **how** you use reload will be usefull, are you using `%aimport` ? Otherwise it won't reload, keep in mind that not everything can be reloaded, and even less deep-reloaded. So you might be just hitting an impossible case.

Comment: sorry. I used
`%load_ext autoreload
autoreload 2`

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for the late response, I've just stumbled upon a similar problem.

In your **run.ipynb**, have you tried:

```
import pertussis
pertussis.check()
```

Or

```
%load_ext autoreload 
%autoreload 1
```

then

```
%aimport pertussis
check = pertussis.check  # optional shortcut
check()
```

Comment: I tried all of those. The reason is probably because ipython has a hard time doing deep-import. I moved all my sub modules into `.py` files instead of sub-folder with init.

Comment: my class stopped being autoreloaded mysteriously when using `%autoreload` but using `%aimport` fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe this is an iPython issue, but is due to the nature of `from` imports.

The following is from *Learning Python Oreilly, p798 (5th ed.)*

> ...because `from` copies (assigns) names when run, there's no link back to the modules where the names came from. Names imported with `from` simply become references to objects, which happen to have been referenced by the same names in the importee when the `from` ran.

A workaround is to use `import` and name qualification. For example:

```py
import pertussis
pertussis.check()
```

Then in **oof.py**:

```py
import pertussis # now must use full name qualification
def check_2():
  print ("Hello")
```