# How do I reload a module after changing it?

Tags: pycharm

Python Console with Python 3.4.2

I defined a function in a module which runs correctly in Python Console in PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.4:
ReloadTest.py:

```
def reloadtest(x):
    print("Version A: {}".format(x))
```

Python Console:

```
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:15:05) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>>> from ReloadTest import reloadtest
>>> reloadtest(1)
Version A: 1
```

After I modified the function to "Version B", PyCharm can't find the change, and `importlib.reload(ReloadTest)` gives me error.
I must reload the Python Console or restart PyCharm every time I modify a module. What did I do wrong? What is the best way to handle this?

ReloadTest.py:

```
def reloadtest(x):
    print("Version B: {}".format(x))
```

Python Console:

```
>>> reloadtest(1)
Version A: 1
>>> from ReloadTest import reloadtest
>>> reloadtest(1)
Version A: 1
>>> import importlib
>>> importlib.reload(ReloadTest)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ReloadTest' is not defined
>>> from ReloadTest import reloadtest
>>> reloadtest(1)
Version A: 1
>>> import ReloadTest
>>> reloadtest(1)
Version A: 1
```

Comment: Use IPython and its [autoreload](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html) function. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Get it to work!
Instead of `from Module import function`, I should import the whole module `import Module`, then call the function by `Module.function()`. This is because

```
from ReloadTest import reloadtest
```

and

```
importlib.reload(ReloadTest)
```

can't go together.

```
>>> import ReloadTest
>>> ReloadTest.reloadtest(1)
Version A: 1
```

After making changes:

```
>>> importlib.reload(ReloadTest)
<module 'ReloadTest' from 'C:\\...\\ReloadTest.py'>
>>> ReloadTest.reloadtest(2)
Version B: 2
```

Comment: I got confused by all the "reload" as a function and "reload" in the module name but for whoever is also confused, you should import the reload function from importlib first, then do reload(your_module_name)

Answer (score 43):

You can instruct Pycharm to automatically reload modules upon changing by adding the following lines to `Settings`->`Build, Execution, Deployment`->`Console`->`Python Console` in the `Starting script`:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

[image]

Update: This function requires IPython (`pip install ipython`) as described here: [Reloading submodules in IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364050/reloading-submodules-in-ipython)

Comment: This gives a syntax error for me. (I tried both with and without the percentage symbol).

Comment: For me too (PyCharm Version 2019.3.1, Python Version 3.8)

Comment: @MattR0se, perhaps IPython is not installed for you. Can you install it using `pip install ipython`

Comment: @MorrisFranken thank you, that's what I was missing.

Comment: Works like a charm! No need to reimport any modules/functions, change is automatically detected and function reloaded.

Comment: I got a syntax error from `%load_ext` but had iPython installed. Problem was fixed with a forced reinstall  of iPython in an Anaconda prompt: `conda activate xxx`, `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall ipython`

Answer (score 34):

I took me some time to understand the previous answer... And also, that answer is not very practical if the chuck of code you need to run is in the middle of a script that you do not feel like modifying for running it once.

You can simply do:

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(my_module)
from my_module import my_function
```

Then, you can run your code with the updated version of the function.

Works with PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2

Edit w.r.t. first comment:
This only works if you first imported the module itself (otherwise you get an error as said in the first comment).

```
import my_module
from my_module import my_function
# Now calls a first version of the function
# Then you change the function
import importlib
importlib.reload(my_module)
from my_module import my_function
# Now calls the new version of the function
```

Comment: Your answer is exactly the same as what my original question says, which causes a NameError and it doesn't work. Now I tried with PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.3 again, it is still exactly like it was before. I am wondering what makes mine different from yours.

Comment: @armlet Indeed, I forgot to mention that this only works if you first import the module so its name is defined. I edited my answer :)

Comment: In the light of my better knowledge of Python now, your first answer is similar to mine, however at that time, it took me some time to actually make it work. So, I'll leave this answer here for new users like I was who may get confused about how to do if their modified function is called at many places in their code, and if they made their call with the function names directly.

Answer (score 5):

Since this question asked specifically about PyCharm, please check out the answer on the [PyCharm Support site](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206601215--re-importing-module-while-in-Console-doesn-t-update-the-code). This answer is almost identical to @wokbot's, the distinction is that PyCharm removes the need to `import importlib`. It also uses the `from ... import ...` trick after `import ...` to make typing easier if you plan to use `reloadtest` frequently.

```
In[2]: import ReloadTest
In[3]: from ReloadTest import reloadtest
In[4]: reloadtest(1)
Out[4]: Version A: 1
```

...make changes

```
In[5]: reload(ReloadTest)
Out[5]: <module 'ReloadTest' from 'C:\\...\\ReloadTest.py'>
In[6]: from ReloadTest import reloadtest
In[7] reloadtest(2)
Out[7]Version B: 2
```

Comment: With IPython you can use [autoreload](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html), e.g. `%load_ext autoreload` and `%autoreload 2`

Comment: @vczm: Since you can use the IPython console in PyCharm, your comment would be the perfect answer to the question. Please consider to write an answer with it.