# Why does autoreload not work for PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, ipython

As many others, I am running into the issue of PyCharm not using the newer version of a function in a different file when the function is imported into a .ipynb. The behaviour is as follows: I run the ipynb, importing the function. I change the function in a seperate .py file. I rerun the ipynb and the unchanged version of the function is still in use. I tried to fix this with the proposed fix found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60099037/5587736. However, this doesn't change anything. I need help running through this, because this fix seems to work for others.

Comment: are you opening .ipynb in PyCharm?

Comment: Yes, I edit both the ipynb and py files in PyCharm, and use PyCharm to run the interactive cells in the ipynb.

Comment: Add ```%load_ext autoreload \n %autoreload 2``` at the top of the ipynb and then you can try running the modified function

Comment: At the top meaning in the first cell? Or above the first cell?

Comment: First cell should be fine actually