# Failure to use updated import file after alteration when using Jupyter for python development

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

Sorry for the awkwardly phrased title. But here's the situation. I am using Jupyter to do some Python development. I am editing an import file, but when I run the program that is doing the importing, it does not use the newest save, it just uses (apparently) the version that is last in its stack.

I stopped the kernel and ran the program again, to no avail. I started a new notebook, copy and pasted the code, and that time it did freshly import the imports.

Is there a way to streamline this procedure so as to avoid having to start a new notebook every time I edit a source file?

First file:

```
# the_import.py
def doStuff():
    ...
```

Second file:

```
# main program
import the_import

def doOtherStuff():
    ...
# When I run this program, it does not use the newest save
# of the_import.py unless a new Jupyter notebook is started.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you kill the IPython notebook server and restart it, you will end up with a new kernel instance.  You should you start your workflow after restarting and opening a notebook again by running all cells.  In the top menu, before you do anything else, first select "Cell->Run all"

Comment: I don't think this addresses the issue. The question occurs because Jupyter does not reload external files by default.  see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5399339/638048