# Developing classes in ipython - dependencies not reloading

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, tdd, ipython

I am developing a bunch of inter-related classes in python with unit tests. I run the classes and tests though ipython as I go along. Using :

```
%run my_test_script_or_harness.py
```

Running this script may highlight a bug in another class, or script which I can then fix. However my problem is that I cannot get the dependencies to reload correctly. I can reload the class I am running, or the test class but this does not reload all of the other classes that I may be changing whilst debugging. IPython seems to cache the other classes, and static methods so they dont get reloaded.

This is really frustrating as I cannot run the scripts after fixing the bugs, as it thinks the old code is still there.

I have tried running:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

from here

[Reloading submodules in IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364050/reloading-submodules-in-ipython)

but that did not help.

What am I doing wrong? Should I be grouping the classes in some other way - will this help.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: You can't if your classes contained `os level` data(interactive). `python abc.py` not equal to `%run abc.py `

Comment: I figure there must be a way around it... or hope!