# Debug a function in python in a dynamic manner

Tags: python, function, debugging, ipython

I have a python function

```
def My_Function():
    Some Codes
    return Something
```

I want to change `Some Codes` in `My_Function` as see the effects in Ipython console. So I modify `Some Codes` and save the corresponding `.py` file and import the function in Ipython console: `import My_Function`. However, when I execute `My_Function` in Ipython, the old version is executed not the modified one. Why?

Comment: A better `reload` SO question for `ipython` is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364050/reloading-submodules-in-ipython

Answer (score 1):

Use [`importlib.reload(module)`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload).

Comment: This is a Py3.4 method, Py2 is different.