# modification in spyder not feeding back on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, spyder

I have modified a function in a file in Spyder (and save it). Now, I rerun a cell that calls that function on my Jupyter Notebook and the modification that I made on my Spyder file does not seem to have effects on my Notebook, still mentioning an error that I had previously.

The only solution I have found to avoid this is to close the Notebook (by ctrl+C and deactivating command on Anaconda prompt and rerun the Notebook).

Of course, it's not so convenient... Is it possible to make it more efficiently ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reloading submodules in IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364050/reloading-submodules-in-ipython)

Comment: Yes, the right solution is the one proposed by the comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restart the kernel in jupyter instead of exiting and relaunching the app.

Then you need to re-execute the cells with the import statements.
(use restart and clear output)

[image]

There is also a jupyter magic function to reload modules documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364050/reloading-submodules-in-ipython):

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

Comment: Thanks, it's slightly better indeed !

Comment: Thanks. I linked to a better answer that mostly solves your inconvenience.