# When importing a module, I get a NameError about certain variable not being defined (even though it is)

Tags: python, oop

So I am trying to import a module/script (.py file) into a Jupyter notebook, mainly for readability and conciseness. But then, when I try to run the class in the script, I get the following Error message:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-4d8cbba46ed0> in <module>()
      8 
      9 test_KMeans = KMeans(k=3, maxiter=1000, tol=1e-9)
---> 10 cluster_center = test_KMeans.fit(X)
     11 clusters = test_KMeans.predict(X)
     12 

~/KMeans.py in fit(self, X)
     42         #Choose k random rows of X as the initial cluster centers.
     43         initial_cluster_centers = []
---> 44 
     45         sample = np.random.randint(0,m,size=k)
     46 

NameError: name 'maxiter' is not defined
```

Here is my script:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

k = 3
maxiter = 1000
tol = 1e-9

class KMeans:
    """A K-Means object class. Implements basic k-means clustering.

    Attributes:
        k (int): The number of clusters
        maxiter (int): The maximum number of iterations
        tol (float): A convergence tolerance
    """
    def __init__(self, k, maxiter, tol):
        """Set the paramters.

        Parameters:
            k (int): The number of clusters
            maxiter (int): The maximum number of iterations
            tol (float): A convergence tolerance
        """
        k = 3
        maxiter = 1000
        tol = 1e-9

        self.k = k   # Initialize some attributes.
        self.maxiter = maxiter
        self.tol = tol

    def fit(self, X):
        """Accepts an mxn matrix X of m data points with n features.
        """
        m,n = X.shape
        k = 3
        maxiter = 1000
        tol = 1e-9
        self.m = m
        self.n = n

        #Choose k random rows of X as the initial cluster centers.
        initial_cluster_centers = []

        sample = np.random.randint(0,m,size=k)

        initial_cluster_centers = X[sample, :]

        # Run the k-means iteration until consecutive centers are within the convergence tolerance, or until 
        # iterating the maximum number of times.
        iterations = 0
        old_cluster = np.zeros(initial_cluster_centers.shape)
        new_cluster = initial_cluster_centers

        while iterations < maxiter or np.linalg.norm(old_cluster - new_cluster) >= tol:
            #assign each data point to the cluster center that is closest, forming k clusters
            clusters = np.zeros(m)
            for i in range(0,m):
                distances = np.linalg.norm(X[i] - initial_cluster_centers, ord=2, axis=1) # axis=1 was crucial
                cluster = np.argmin(distances)                                            #in getting this to work
                clusters[i] = cluster
            # Store the old/initial centroid values
            old_cluster = np.copy(new_cluster)
            #Recompute the cluster centers as the means of the new clusters
            for i in range(k):
                points = [X[j] for j in range(m) if clusters[j] == i]
                new_cluster[i] = np.mean(points, axis=0)
                #If a cluster is empty, reassign the cluster center as a random row of X.
                if new_cluster[i] == []:
                    new_cluster[i] = X[np.random.randint(0,m,size=1)]
            iterations += 1

        #Save the cluster centers as attributes.
        self.new_cluster = new_cluster

        #print("New cluster centers:\n", new_cluster)

        return new_cluster

    def predict(self, X):
        """Accept an l × n matrix X of data.
        """
        # Return an array of l integers where the ith entry indicates which 
        # cluster center the ith row of X is closest to.
        clusters = np.zeros(self.m)
        for i in range(0,self.m):
            distances = np.linalg.norm(X[i] - self.new_cluster, ord=2, axis=1)
            cluster = np.argmin(distances)
            clusters[i] = cluster

        print("\nClusters:", clusters)

        return clusters
```

Then I attempt to do the following:

```
from KMeans import KMeans

X = features_scaled

# k = 3
# maxiter = 1000
# tol = 1e-9

test_KMeans = KMeans(k=3, maxiter=1000, tol=1e-9)
cluster_center = test_KMeans.fit(X)
clusters = test_KMeans.predict(X)

pca = PCA(n_components=2)

pr_components = pca.fit_transform(X) # these are the first 2 principal components

#plot the first two principal components as a scatter plot, where the color of each point is det by the clusters
plt.scatter(pr_components[:,0], pr_components[:,1],
           c=clusters, edgecolor='none', alpha=0.5, #color by clusters
            cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('tab10', 3)) 
plt.xlabel('principal component 1')
plt.ylabel('principal component 2')
plt.colorbar()
plt.title("K-Means Clustering:")
plt.show()
```

Upon running the above section of code, I get the NameError I described. I don't understand why it is telling me that `maxiter` is not defined. You'll see I defined the variables `k, maxiter, tol` multiple times in the script trying to get it to work, but nothing has. I had `self.maxiter` and `self.tol` at one point but that didn't fix it either.

I know this code works because I have used it multiple times now. Originally I just defined those variables k, maxiter, and tol.. then instantiated the class and called the fit and predict methods, and since they were stored as attributes with self, everything worked fine. but now that I try to import it as a module I have no idea why it is not working.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: Here is what my code would look like in a single cell in a Jupyter notebook.. It does run and work in this case:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

class KMeans:
    """A K-Means object class. Implements basic k-means clustering.

    Attributes:
        k (int): The number of clusters
        maxiter (int): The maximum number of iterations
        tol (float): A convergence tolerance
    """
    def __init__(self, k, maxiter, tol):
        """Set the paramters.

        Parameters:
            k (int): The number of clusters
            maxiter (int): The maximum number of iterations
            tol (float): A convergence tolerance
        """
        self.k = k   # Initialize some attributes.
        self.maxiter = maxiter
        self.tol = tol

    def fit(self, X):
        """Accepts an mxn matrix X of m data points with n features.
        """
        m,n = X.shape
        self.m = m
        self.n = n

        #Choose k random rows of X as the initial cluster centers.
        initial_cluster_centers = []

        sample = np.random.randint(0,m,size=self.k)

        initial_cluster_centers = X[sample, :]

        # Run the k-means iteration until consecutive centers are within the convergence tolerance, or until 
        # iterating the maximum number of times.
        iterations = 0
        old_cluster = np.zeros(initial_cluster_centers.shape)
        new_cluster = initial_cluster_centers

        while iterations < maxiter or np.linalg.norm(old_cluster - new_cluster) >= tol:
            #assign each data point to the cluster center that is closest, forming k clusters
            clusters = np.zeros(m)
            for i in range(0,m):
                distances = np.linalg.norm(X[i] - initial_cluster_centers, ord=2, axis=1) # axis=1 was crucial
                cluster = np.argmin(distances)                                            #in getting this to work
                clusters[i] = cluster
            # Store the old/initial centroid values
            old_cluster = np.copy(new_cluster)
            #Recompute the cluster centers as the means of the new clusters
            for i in range(k):
                points = [X[j] for j in range(m) if clusters[j] == i]
                new_cluster[i] = np.mean(points, axis=0)
                #If a cluster is empty, reassign the cluster center as a random row of X.
                if new_cluster[i] == []:
                    new_cluster[i] = X[np.random.randint(0,m,size=1)]
            iterations += 1

        #Save the cluster centers as attributes.
        self.new_cluster = new_cluster

        #print("New cluster centers:\n", new_cluster)

        return new_cluster

    def predict(self, X):
        """Accept an l × n matrix X of data.
        """
        # Return an array of l integers where the ith entry indicates which 
        # cluster center the ith row of X is closest to.
        clusters = np.zeros(self.m)
        for i in range(0,self.m):
            distances = np.linalg.norm(X[i] - self.new_cluster, ord=2, axis=1)
            cluster = np.argmin(distances)
            clusters[i] = cluster

        print("\nClusters:", clusters)

        return clusters

X = features_scaled

k = 3
maxiter = 1000
tol = 1e-9

test_KMeans = KMeans(k,maxiter,tol)
test_KMeans.fit(X)
clusters = test_KMeans.predict(X)

pca = PCA(n_components=2)

pr_components = pca.fit_transform(X) # these are the first 2 principal components

#plot the first two principal components as a scatter plot, where the color of each point is det by the clusters
plt.scatter(pr_components[:,0], pr_components[:,1],
           c=clusters, edgecolor='none', alpha=0.5, #color by clusters
            cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('tab10', 3)) 
plt.xlabel('principal component 1')
plt.ylabel('principal component 2')
plt.colorbar()
plt.title("K-Means Clustering:")
plt.show()
```

Comment: It's usually very bad practice to define `k, maxiter, tol` as global variables your way. Could you show the directory structure related to these scripts/notebooks

Comment: global as in when I define them right after importing numpy and pca? I only did that to try to fix the issue

Comment: the script and notebook are all in the same directory... /home/user and then both files are in there

Comment: The traceback seems to show Jupyter is out of sync with the current state of code in Kmeans.py (because it points to line 44... which is empty). If you quit and restart Jupyter, does the problem go away?

Comment: @Javier, global means they're defined outside the class. You could define them inside the class (e.g. as attributes) or be passed to the classes as parameters.

Comment: @unutbu that totally fixed the problem!!! Haha wow, thank you so much! This is super helpful to know for the future, as next time I wont go crazy spending over an hour thinking it was an issue with my code and how I defined variables and trying to find the problem... How does Jupyter get out of sync with the code in the script?

Comment: @unutbu if you want to make that an answer I will accept it btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traceback seems to show Jupyter is out of sync with the current state of code in Kmeans.py (because it points to line 44... which is empty). Therefore, if the computation doesn't take too long, you might try fixing the problem by quitting and restarting Jupyter.

Python executes the module's code when the module is imported.
If you make changes to the module's code after the module is imported, those changes are not
reflected in the state of the Python interpreter.
This may explain why the Jupyter notebook's error seemed out of sync with the state of Kmeans.py.

Instead of quitting and restarting Python, you can also [reload modules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/437589/190597). For example, in Python3.4 or newer, you could use

```
import sys
import importlib
from Kmeans import Kmeans

# make changes to Kmeans.py
importlib.reload(sys.modules['Kmeans'])
# now the Python interpreter should be aware of changes made to Kmeans.py
```

However, using IPython, there is an easier way. You could [enable autoreloading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5399339/190597):

From the command line run:

```
ipython profile create
```

Then edit `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py` by adding

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = ['autoreload']     
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%autoreload 2']
```

Quit and restart IPython to make this change effective.
Now, IPython will automatically reload any module when a change is made to the underlying code which defines that module. In most situations autoreload works well, but there are situations where it may fail to reload the module. See [the docs](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html) for more on autoreload and its caveats.

Comment: Module reloading can cause a lot of weird issues, though, especially with `from` imports and/or old versions of classes hanging around. Restarting is slower but a lot more reliable.