# Unable to use updated version of python file when using it in a jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I created a python file with some functions that I call several times from another jupyter notebook for testing, etc. However whilst testing I found an error in one of the functions, and fixed the issue in the origin python function and saved it. However when i called the function from the external python file in my jupyter notebook, it kept calling the unupdated version of the function instead of the updated version, I tried closing and reopening the python file without any success, eventually I got it to work after I closed my jupyter notebook and shutdown the notebook and then restarted it. 
This is quite inconvenient though especially for testing purposes so I was wondering if there is an better way to use the external python file especially when I update it...

Below is how I get the other python file in jupyter notebook, not sure if something there might be messing things up

```py
from external_functions import *
```

Comment: Restart Kernel and Clear All Outputs, then rerun

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reloading submodules in IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364050/reloading-submodules-in-ipython)

Comment: Thanks for the responses, is there a method that works without having clearing all variables and essentially reloading the entire notebook?