# Can't import installed packages in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

If I run the following in a Jupyter notebook :

```
!pip install gTTS

from gtts import gTTS
```

I get the following output:

```
Requirement already satisfied: gTTS in c:\users\username\.conda\envs\gpu\lib\site-packages (2.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: click in c:\users\username\.conda\envs\gpu\lib\site-packages (from gTTS) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\username\.conda\envs\gpu\lib\site-packages (from gTTS) (1.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: gtts-token>=1.1.3 in c:\users\username\.conda\envs\gpu\lib\site-packages (from gTTS) (1.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\username\.conda\envs\gpu\lib\site-packages (from gTTS) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in c:\users\username\.conda\envs\gpu\lib\site-packages (from gTTS) (4.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\username\.conda\envs\gpu\lib\site-packages (from requests->gTTS) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\username\.conda\envs\gpu\lib\site-packages (from requests->gTTS) (2019.11.28)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\username\.conda\envs\gpu\lib\site-packages (from requests->gTTS) (1.25.7)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in c:\users\username\.conda\envs\gpu\lib\site-packages (from requests->gTTS) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>=1.2 in c:\users\username\.conda\envs\gpu\lib\site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->gTTS) (1.9.5)


ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gtts'
```

What should I do?

Edit: `from gtts import gTTS` works perfectly fine in the terminal.

Update:

TL;DR: Still facing this problem

Even after 5 months I haven't been able to narrow down what the problem is. The answers below are workarounds but don't actually address the main problem. Why is this happening? And `jupyter notebook` isn't the only tool where I am facing this issue. This is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61986052/vscode-terminal-doesnt-activate-conda-environment) I asked titled "VSCode terminal doesn't activate conda environment". Similarly with Sublime text. I can't set up the internal console to build from environments.

Comment: can you confirm is it successfully installed?

Comment: from gtts import gTTS works perfectly fine in the terminal.

Comment: For some packages, you need to restart the jupyter kernel after `!pip install` to use it. Also [autoreload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364050/reloading-submodules-in-ipython) might help avoiding this.

Comment: I have always restarted the kernel. Even a complete reboot of the system doesn't work :(

Comment: This problem is still haunting me. This time with `apiclient` from youtube API. Exact same issue. everything works fine on the terminal but can't import it in juptyer notebook!!

Comment: I had this problem on MacOS, when installing jupyter with "brew install jupyter". had to uninstall and install it with "pip install jupyter". After this it works. Must be brew messing up the install with paths or something. Also something I noticed before is that if you do "pip install jupyter" at system level, and again in a pipenv, the system level jupyter will mess with the pipenv version by setting system paths, and appending its paths into the path before the pipenv installed ones. So just remove all jupyters and install in pipenv if this is case.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
!conda install gTTS
from gtts import gTTS
```

Because you are using Conda, conda should be used instead of pip

Comment: PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - gtts

Comment: maybe try to update the pip firstly (!pip install --upgrade pip), then use the command you had before with pip

Comment: Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\yatin\.conda\envs\gpu\lib\site-packages (19.3.1)

Comment: adding the additional channel to conda if you can, but I just checked in conda-forge, it doesn't have the gTTS library, so you probably have to go back with pip, or package it and add to conda-forge by yourself to benefit the rest of conda users.

Answer (score 0):

pip install version to your default python version which is python2, you should do

```
!python3 -m pip install gTTS
from gtts import gTTs
```

Comment: Python was not found but can be installed from the Microsoft Store: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?linkID=2082640