# Visual Studio Code terminal doesn't activate Conda environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda, environment

I read [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351596/activating-anaconda-environment-in-vscode) on a similar issue, but the suggestions there don't seem to be working. I installed Visual Studio Code on my Windows machine and added the Python extension. Then I changed the Python path for my project to `C:\Users\username\.conda\envs\tom\python.exe`. The `.vscode/settings.json` has this in it:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\username\\.conda\\envs\\tom\\python.exe"
}
```

The status bar in Visual Studio Code also shows:

[image]

But when I do `conda env list` even after doing `conda activate tom` in the terminal I get the output:

```
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
tom                      C:\Users\username\.conda\envs\tom
```

Instead of:

```
# conda environments:
#
base                     C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
tom                   *  C:\Users\username\.conda\envs\tom
```

Also the packages not installed in base don't get imported when I try `python app.py`. What should I do?

`where python` runs, but it doesn't give any output.

Also,

```
import os
import sys
os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
```

gives

```
'C:\\Python38'
```

Comment: I have the same issue. It used to work before and I did not have start VS code from the conda prompt ever. Also, the correct python.exe (from the env) is used, just the dependencies are not found.

Comment: Could the issue be PowerShell is default shell in VSCode, but miniconda, miniforge, and mambaforge only work with CMD.EXE (on windows)?  When .bat files are run from PowerShell instead of CMD shell the env vars are set but then tossed when CMD.EXE process immediately exits, never updating the PowerShell environment.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

First, open the Anaconda prompt (*[How to access Anaconda command prompt in Windows 10 (64-bit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47914980/how-to-access-anaconda-command-prompt-in-windows-10-64-bit)*), and type:

```
conda activate tom
```

To activate your virtual environment.

Then to open Visual Studio Code in this active environment, type

```
code
```

And it should work.

Comment: No I didn't get any error... It opened vscode, i added my project and the tried ```conda env list``` in the terminal... I am still getting base as my activate env..

Comment: It could be due to the way VSCode was installed. Try to uninstall it, and re-install from the Anaconda-Navigator

Comment: You can do a uninstall and then reinstall of the Anaconda-Navigator, and then VSCode will be available to install from there again. The previous removal of VSCode might have been the Anaconda installation, it needs to be the system installation. This should work.

Comment: Hm... I was afraid you might say this... I will wait for a couple of days... If I don't find any alternative or solution then I guess I will a reinstall..

Comment: If you had installed many packages specifically into your virtual environment, you can run the command: conda list, and copy the package names and versions to a file for easier reinstall. (will only show packages installed with conda, for pip installs you must open the actual installation folder to see the packages).

Comment: What if I copy the package folders into a pen-drive, remove anaconda and then reinstall it, but this time on my D drive instead of my C drive... Will pasting the folders in my `envs` directory work?

Comment: I tried it, but just with few packages. But you could run into dependency resolution issues I fear. However, reinstalling packages won't take up that much time I think. As long as you record the current state of both package name and version it should be a smooth process.

Answer (score 42):

I was facing the same issue for a long time and nothing seemed to work. Out of nowhere, VS Code suggested me the following in a notification prompt:

> We noticed you're using a conda environment. If you are experiencing
> issues with this environment in the integrated terminal, we recommend
> that you let the Python extension change
> "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv" to false in your user settings.

I clicked `yes` on it and worked. You can also manually set this in your settings.json as follows:

1. Press `Shift + Command + P` to open command palette.
2. Type settings.json and select `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)
3. In the JSON file, add the key-value pair `"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false`
4. Save the JSON file

Comment: Similar situation here, but I had to create a new Terminal from the Terminal Menu for it to work. Exiting VS Code, activating the environment, etc. had no effect.  Some details here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environments-and-terminal-windows

Answer (score 34):

1. In Vscode hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to open your terminal.
2. Then within the terminal type: `conda init`.
3. Close and reopen the terminal.
4. Use Conda normally.

Comment: This worked for me, is a permanent fix, and fixed another issue with VS Code not finding conda. One effect of running `conda init` is to add the `condabin` folder to PATH, which puts `conda.bat` on the path, but not python (see @peter-c answer)

Comment: Running conda init printed out some checks and a final "Nothing changed" but it did fixed that for me. I guess nothing needed to change.

Comment: IMO this is the best approach. For people with `QWERTZ` (ger, aus, ..) keyboard layout, replace the shortcut in the first step with `ctrl`+ `ö`

Comment: if you are just playing around this might have unintended consequences after miniconda/anaconda uninstall, to fix it you might need to fiddle with registry: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66335300/cmd-crashes-with-exit-code-1-after-uninstalling-anaconda

Answer (score 20):

[image]

I was helped by switching the terminal from powershell to cmd

Comment: Yeah doublecheck your terminal under powershell or cmd !

Answer (score 8):

I've already tried most solutions to solve this problem. However, those didn't work. Following the steps that [Sabito 錆兎](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11573842/sabito-%e9%8c%86%e5%85%8e) [mentioned in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67298127/11573842), I finally solved it.

Solution 1:

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>
2. Type `terminal: select default profile`
3. Choose **Command Prompt**.

   [image: Image for 'choose Command Prompt']
4. Open a new terminal and you can use cmd to do such things.

Another way to change the default terminal is (in case you forget the command):

1. On the right top of the terminal panel, <kbd>click</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> (Launch Profiles)
2. Select default Profile
3. Choose which you want
   in this way, you can also open configure terminal settings

Solution 2:

1. Do what [Sabito 錆兎](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11573842/sabito-%e9%8c%86%e5%85%8e) [said in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67298127/11573842).
2. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>
3. Type `Python: Select Interpreter`
4. Choose which env in conda you need.
   You can also select on the bottom panel.
5. Unnecessary step: in `vscode-settings.json`, make sure that if this line exists then the argument is true:

   ```
   "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,
   ```

   Now, vscode will automatically change your env in your terminal according to your
   choice, like this:

   #### CMD

   When I choose `base:conda`, I open a new terminal. In the console, it shows

   ```
   F:\GitHub\t>E:/Anaconda/Install/Scripts/activate 
   (base) F:\GitHub\t>conda activate base 
   (base) F:\GitHub\t>
   ```

   When I choose `python3.8:conda`it shows

   ```
   F:\GitHub\t>E:/Anaconda/Install/Scripts/activate 
   (base) F:\GitHub\t>conda activate python3.8 
   (python3.8) F:\GitHub\t>
   ```

   #### PowerShell

   When I choose `python3.8:conda`. it shows

   ```
   (base) PS F:\GitHub\t> conda activate python3.8 
   (python3.8) PS F:\GitHub\t>
   ```

   When I choose `base:conda`, it shows

   ```
   (base) PS F:\GitHub\t> conda activate base  
   (base) PS  F:\GitHub\t>
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Activating anaconda virtual environment in vs code

1. Go to the menu bar and click on Terminal.
2. Type: `conda init`
3. Close this terminal and open a new one
4. In the new terminal window, Type `conda info --envs`
   (Your conda virtual env should be there in the list)
5. Type `conda activate name_of_venv`

Comment: If the Terminal isn't properly configured, the command ```conda init``` will not work because ```conda``` is not in the search path.  On my system, it is in ```C:\Users\<user ID>\Anaconda3\Scripts```.  You therefore may need to use ```C:\Users\<user ID>\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda init```.

Answer (score 3):

1. Type: conda init
2. switch to cmd terminal, because the shell terminal has problems
3. enjoy

it's work for me in vscode

Comment: This worked for me when the Conda Environments were not detected by default, and manually added in Global folder of the Python Environments extension.

Conda init worked too, with PowerShell. But I chose not to use that method as I did not want conda activated all the time.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be because the Anaconda installation recommends not changing the windows PATH to reference anaconda, as it can clash with other installations, I had no problems when my PATH variable was modified. It seems like vs code (or most likely the Python extension) is still not activating anaconda correctly itself.

Answer (score 1):

If `conda init` fails, it might not just be a problem of conda missing in the search path. In my case it was because PowerShell did not have the rights to load the `profile.ps1`, see [The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69934939/11154841).

In that case, and if you have not yet done so, install `PowerShell 7` in parallel to `PowerShell 5` and fill the `C:\Users\USER\Documents\PowerShell\profile.ps1` with:

```
#region conda initialize
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
(& "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell" "hook") | Out-String | Invoke-Expression
#endregion
```

[image]

Then add the new PowerShell 7 terminal to vscode, see [How to add anaconda powershell to vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69935706/11154841).

The terminal menu:

[image]

And `conda init` and the activation of the chosen Python interpreter's environment that you see in the status bar of VSCode will run automatically any time you open `PowerShell 7`.

Remark from a comment: you will likely need `conda init` to update your `PowerShell 7` profile.

Comment: This worked for me, but I ran conda init which updated the PowerShell profile.

Answer (score 1):

The virtual environment can be activated in the VSCode terminal, but the Python version is not switched.

The solution is to select “bash” in VSCode, everything is alright.

Comment: I think your answer is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69974309/11573842)

Answer (score 0):

`PythonPath` is no longer used by the default Python plugin now (as of 2021). Instead, you can add the interpreter path using the following:

1. In a terminal, run the following to get the path to your env:

```
conda activate <name of your env> && which python
```

2. Then set the VSCode JSON setting (either user or workspace):

```
{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "<Path to your env>",
}
```

3. Restart VSCode completely to see your env in the terminal, as it seems that VSCode sometimes caches the terminal window.

(All this assumes that there are no other messed up settings in your vscode. If there are, look at other answers to this question).

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be many different causes for conda not being automatically activated.  I'm using python in wsl2 with bash as my shell and setting the following two settings to true fixed it for me:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case when you:

1. installed Python and set it to the Windows PATH
2. refused to add Anaconda to PATHs as default Python interpreter during installation
3. vs code finds the conda, but not conda cmdlet

**Solution:**

Let vs code add the conda directory as the first search path in Windows PATH for you when it is running. This can be done both for the whole vs code and for a specific workspace.

**Entire vs code:**

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)
3. add the path to the location of your conda.exe, in my case it's C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Scripts\

```json
 "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
        "PATH": "C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3\\Scripts\\;${env:PATH}"
    }
```

**Specific workspace:**

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)

```json
    "settings":
    {
        "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
            "PATH": "C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3\\Scripts\\;${env:PATH}"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks so much. I did work as tutorial and it run

I've already tried most solutions to solve this problem. However, those didn't work. Following the steps that Sabito 錆兎 mentioned in their answer, I finally solved it.

Solution 1:

ctrl+shift+p

Type terminal: select default profile

Choose Command Prompt.

thanks a lot

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34804374)

Answer (score 0):

In my case simply choosing "Command Prompt" instead of "Poweshell" as VS-code terminal worked. I am not sure if there are any disadvantages of using command prompt over Powershell because I am not a heavy windows user. Not for python programming at least. I will be exploring more and will add edits later if I found something.

Answer (score 0):

The focus of this answer is to get the conda python environments to work with the Python Environments extension in vs code. There are many ways to do this, each has different effects and implications on how you want to interact with Python in vs code.

My Environment: Windows 10, Conda 23.7.4, Conda installed in C:\apps & I am using PowerShell 7 not windows PowerShell.

1. Opening vs-code via Anaconda navigator or type `code` in conda prompt. This loads Conda environments in to Python Environments window. Includes nice ui conponents. This also removes conda from the powershell terminal. So you can write "activate myenv".
2. If you want to open vs code directly, add to settings:

```
"python.condaPath": "C:\\apps\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\",
"python.venvPath": "C:\\apps\\Anaconda3\\envs",
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",
```

This method puts conda environments in Global and has another folder for Venv.

3. The following will run base conda in all powershell terminals: in conda prompt run `conda init` & add to settings:

```
"python.condaPath": "C:\\apps\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\",
"python.venvPath": "C:\\apps\\Anaconda3\\envs",
```

Notes:

- It can sometimes take a while to detect the conda environments
- there is a difference between loading via conda prompt `code` and navigator
- sometimes some methods work with some environments and not others.

Answer (score 0):

Switching the terminal from powershell to git bash or command prompt fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code now allows you to make a new terminal profile which helps with conda on Windows: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles

Basically, you open up `settings.json` and just add the following:

```
"Miniconda": {
    "path": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "args": ["/K", "C:\\Users\\$USER\\miniconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat C:\\Users\\${env:USERNAME}\\miniconda3"],
    "icon": "terminal-cmd"
}
```

You can then set it as the default profile.