# Wrong conda python environment version showing on visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

(Running this on Windows 11) I'm not sure if it's a bug or something I did wrong when updating python, but after updating Python to version 3.9.15 from the conda terminal, VSCode seems to not recognize it at least in the environments tab and when I do Shift+Ctrl+P.

[image: Version discrepancy between used version and displayed version of Python]

What's weirder is that whenever I close and reopen VSCode, it shows the correct version for 5 seconds top-right before suddenly switching back to the older version. This isn't really a major issue since I know I'm using the up-to-date version, just a UI thing I noticed and wanted to see if there's a quick fix.

Comment: Is it possible that you have updated Python in a non-base environment or created a new one while updating Python?

Comment: Could you please also check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61986052/visual-studio-code-terminal-doesnt-activate-conda-environment) answers your question?

Comment: Can you add the python interpreter path in this [picture](https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/docs/python/environments/interpreters-list.png)?