# Visual studio terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

How to convert the following codes in VS Code terminal?

```
conda create -n cluster_topic_model python=3.7 -y
conda activate cluster_topic_model
```

Comment: does this post help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61986052/visual-studio-code-terminal-doesnt-activate-conda-environment

Comment: This is what I did. Open your VSCode to your desired directory. Then press`Ctrl+Shit+P` which opens a section prompting which interpreter to use. Select the python interpreter of your choice. Now assuming you have Anaconda installed on your local device. Now you should again press `Ctrl+Shit+P` and choose your Python kernel as `(base)` which has the `conda` environment. Now go to the `Terminal` tab on the menu bar and open a new terminal. Crucial part: You have to open a `cmd` terminal now and then you can go ahead with your code.

Comment: What happened when you tried to run that code as it already is?

Comment: Thanks so much @Gautam Chettiar, it worked; would you like to add your comment to the answer section?

Comment: Sure, ill add the comment as it is.

Comment: @ Charles Duffy, it would say conda is not recognized!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***The same has been provided in the comment as well. Leaving it here for the rest.***

*This is what I did.*

1. Open your VSCode to your desired directory.
2. Then press `Ctrl+Shit+P` which opens a section prompting which
   interpreter to use.
3. Select the python interpreter of your choice.
4. Now assuming you have Anaconda installed on your local device.
5. Now you should again press `Ctrl+Shit+P` and choose your Python
   kernel as `(base)` which has the `conda` environment.
6. Now go to the `Terminal` tab on the menu bar and open a new
   terminal.

Hope this helps!

Crucial part: You have to open a `cmd` terminal now and then you can go ahead with your code.