# Jupyter uses an outdated version of a function when asked to import from a file

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

In the file `mylibrary.py` I have the function

```
def myfunc(a,b):
    return a+b
```

and in a Jupyter notebook I run

```
import mylibrary
mylibrary.myfunc(1,2)
```

and the output is `3` as expected.

However, when I update the the file `mylibrary.py` so that its contents are

```
def myfunc(a):
    return a+1
```

and run in Jupyter

```
import mylibrary
mylibrary.myfunc(1,2)
```

the output is an error:

```
TypeError: myfunc() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

Apparently Jupyter is still using the old version of `mylibrary.py`. The error persists if I delete the cache created for `mylibrary.py` after I try to import it.

Why is this happening, and how can I correct it? (An obvious workaround would be to define `myfunc` in the Jupyter notebook instead of having it separate, which for now I will do. However, that works around the problem instead of actually fixing it, so that I still don't understand what went wrong and I may fall into a pitfall later as a result. Therefore, I think it's worthwhile to figure out what is going wrong.)

Comment: does this help? [Reloading submodules in IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364050/reloading-submodules-in-ipython)

Comment: Unfortunately, no; I tried running `%load_ext autoreload` followed by `%autoreload 2` but still get the same error.

Comment: I think that you should run `%load_ext autoreload` and `%autoreload 2` prior to importing the file for the first time in a notebook.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried placing both before and after the import and in both cases the old version was still used. For what it's worth, I've just found that running `import importlib` then `import mylibrary` then `mylibrary = importlib.reload(mylibrary)` works, although it's clunky.

Comment: Can't believe this is still an issue after all these years. Only the @BGreen answer seems to work.