# A way to instruct python in jupyter to run selected previous cells

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am working in jupyter notebook and I have more than 100 cells doing different operations on data but depending on my need I want to run just around 25 different cells in every case.

example:

Run cell 20 then 26 then 79 then 43 then do the current cell's code.

Is this even healthy code, or maybe I should rerun over cells and turn them all into functions, maybe.

Comment: this sounds like a bad plan.  :).  One of the key tenets of data science is reproducibility and having a "click plan" on cells isn't it.  As you suggested, I would encapsulate things into functions and in the "execution area" set it up with a sequence of function calls in any particular cell.  My 2 cents.

Comment: It sounds that what you need is a specialised kernel like https://github.com/nbsafety-project/nbsafety or https://github.com/dataflownb/dfkernel.

Comment: But also, you could build a JupyterLab extension that executes cells based on their number. It should be easy.

Comment: well thanks in fact the main problem is that i have already defined my own functions also but when i call them once for testing and after a modification of these external functions and I recall an import for them it doesn't import what's already imported so i have to restart the kernal and rerun over all the cells again and again for every modification i do in the external function.

Comment: This is a very different problem. This just means that you need to enable auto-reload: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364050/reloading-submodules-in-ipython

Comment: Agree this is not a great idea. The only viable use case for Jupyter notebooks is EDA. In my opinion, everything else should be in an IDE like PyCharm, writing base Python scripts.