# Is there any way to use django shell without restarting when change code

Tags: python, django, shell

I use Django `shell_plus` for testing my models and views

But when i get error then i change the code and then i have to restart my `shell_plus`

and then type all commands which i have typed

Is there any way that i don't need to restart shell and i can chnage the code and then test the command again

Answer (score 1):

I personally in such cases just record my session from `shell_plus` to file, and then call this file from within `shell_plus` after manually reloading. Both is possible with iPython, which is used by `shell_plus` by default. (If you don't have iPython installed, just `pip install ipython` and it should automatically work after that, I think).

The recorded script is also often nice to keep as part of the project, as it's basically a small integration test. With minor modifications it could be executed outside shell as a standalone script, which is convenient.

If you definitely want to use reloading, I think this answer might be able to help you:

- [How do you reload a Django model module using the interactive interpreter via “manage.py shell”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890924/how-do-you-reload-a-django-model-module-using-the-interactive-interpreter-via-m).

Answer (score 0):

Doing

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(module_you_changed)
```

works in some cases, but it won't reload all the modules imported by module_you_changed.