# django reload models and import *

Tags: django, python-2.7

here is my code.

```
from app import models
from models import *
def reload1():
    from app import models
    reload(models)
    from app.models import *

def x():
    //do some changes in models
    reload1()
```

The above code is showing a syntax warning.Please help me fixing this issue.
How can i effectively reload models?

Comment: why would you want to do that ??

Comment: because i have made some changes to models dynamically, and without  reloading i cand make use of these changes i made.

Comment: well then your question may be possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890924/how-do-you-reload-a-django-model-module-using-the-interactive-interpreter-via-m

Comment: but its not working.

Comment: reload can be used in module level only. Here you use wildcard import in which you can not reload individual members.

Comment: so what should i do to perform the same action

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this". "Don't do that then." Same advice applies: don't do that. Import the module, not the classes.

Comment: what if i am creating dynamic table, and each time the import differs.

Comment: "Keep it simple, stupid" use some variable that refer to current model like that `cur_model = Table1` then `if some_changes: cur_model = Table2`

Comment: wow what an intelligent answer, GREAT.please dont give such stupid comments.